# selenium headless test headless mode

Tags: java, selenium

I am running selenium test with chromedriver. But now I require the same thing to do in headless mode.

Below is the program, where the headless mode is running great --

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");                    
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));  
element.sendKeys("Guru99"); 
element.submit();           
System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());      
driver.quit();
```

Now here is the problem --
The program ended with an exception when I am trying to read the element with its `id` or `xpath`.

Error is

> No such element found.

How to rectify this error. Any help will we welcome.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: try to add explicit waits before the element.

Comment: @RamanGupta How does the _id_ or _xpath_ looks like which you have tried as in _program ended with an exception when I am trying to read the element with its id or xpath_?

Comment: ID - lst-ib, XPATH - //*[@id="lst-ib"]

Answer (score 1):

import these:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

and use this:

```
WebDriverWait wait5s = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);

WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

WebElement element = wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q")));  

element.sendKeys("Guru99"); 
element.submit();           
System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());      
driver.quit();
```

you shoul be able to find the element by ID, xpath, whatever.